# [fixed and improved]Replacing lines in a file through a button action

Tags: java, file, netbeans, replace

There is a file `Activites.dat`, which takes a format like this:

**Day**
**ActivityName**
**SupervisorName**
**Location**
**Paid?**

e.g. Data

```
Sunday
Advanced Open Water Dive Certificate
Mr.Jones
N/A
Yes

Sunday
Sailing
Mr. Jackson
N/A
Yes

Sunday
Generation Next
Ms.Steele
N/A
Yes
```

Now, I have a button on a frame which displays all the information of the current selected Activity from a table, and the frame works fine; all data of selected activity displays correctly.

What I now need to do is, when the button `btnSave` is pressed, the original values are kept for matching with `Activities.dat` to find out which data needs to be edited/replaced, the current data input by the user are stored, then the new data replaces the old data in the `Activities.dat`

e.g. wanted outcome

**initial**

```
Sunday
Advanced Open Water Dive Certificate
Mr.Jones
N/A
Yes

Sunday
Sailing
Mr. Jackson
N/A
Yes

Sunday
Generation Next
Ms.Steele
N/A
Yes
```

**Edited version**

```
Sunday
Advanced Open Water Dive Certificate
Mr.Jones
N/A
Yes

**Monday**
**Sailing Elite Course**
**Mr.Jonathan**
**HS5**
**No**

Sunday
Generation Next
Ms.Steele
N/A
Yes
```

**My current (not working) code**

```
    private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

//ALL "original-" STRINGS ARE INITIALISED BEFORE

        String nActivityName  =   txtActivityName.getText();
        Object nDay  =   comboboxDay.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String nSupervisor = txtSupervisor.getText();
        String nLocation = txtLocation.getText();
        String nPaid = null;

        //Check which option is selected: Paid or Not Paid
        if(radioYes.isSelected())
        {
            nPaid = radioYes.getText();
        }
        if(radioNo.isSelected())
        {
            nPaid = radioNo.getText();
        }

        File file = new File("Activities.dat");

        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

                while(reader.ready())
                {
                    String RDay = reader.readLine();    
                    String RActivityName = reader.readLine();
                    String RSupervisor = reader.readLine();
                    String RLocation = reader.readLine();
                    String RPaid = reader.readLine();
                    String nothing = reader.readLine();

                    //Match the exact same set of data as the original activity's data before edit.
                    if(RActivityName.equals(originalActivityName))
                    {
                        RDay.replace(RDay, (CharSequence) nDay);
//                                = nDay.toString();
                        RActivityName = nActivityName;
                        RSupervisor = nSupervisor;
                        RLocation = nLocation;
                        RPaid = nPaid;
                        nothing = nothing;
                    }
                    System.out.println(RDay + RActivityName + RSupervisor + RLocation + RPaid);
                }


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
                Logger.getLogger(AddActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

    }
```

I can get as far as storing the original values for comparison and getting the new data, but I do not know how to replace/edit the old data with the new data within `Activities.dat`. How do I do this?

And Yes, I DO know that I have a `BufferedReader`, but am not using it as I don't know where or how to use it in this particular situation.

Comment: Why not read the whole file, edit any number of records in the UI, write the whole file? No need to keep the original data. The end result will be the same, but with much simpler code.

Comment: I've actually tried that, but I ended up with the file just being deleted as a whole, and I'm not familiar too familiar with rewriting a file + saving changes... if possible could you do an answer to this question with a simple pseudocode with the method you mentioned? I can figure it out, just need a few directions, I think...

Comment: You create a loop that goes throught the TableModel one row at a time. Inside that loop your create another loop that goes through every column in the model. Inside that loop you use the getValueAt(...) method to get the data from the model. Then you write the value to a file, then you write your delimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do the "read/write whole files" approach:

1. Create a class that encapsulates a single activity, so you can implement the logic on a higher level than a bunch of strings:

   ```
   class Activity {
     String day;
     String activityName;
     String supervisorName;
     String location;
     String paid;
   }
   ```

   This is a very rough ouline of the class. For brevity, I've not included a proper constructor, getters, `hashCode()`, `equals()` and `toString()`.
2. Create another class that is only concerned with reading and writing activites from/to files. This again serves to make your code easier to understand.

   Think about what you want from that class, these should be the only methods visible to a caller, e.g.

   ```
   /** Write activities to a file. */
   void writeActivities(File file, List<Activity> activities);

   /** Read activities from a file. */
   List<Activity> readActivities(File file);
   ```

   Then implement the methods, e.g.

   ```
   public class ActivityManager {
     // Don't rely on te platform default, use a fixed charset.
     private final static Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

     /** Write activities to a file. */
     void writeActivities(File file, List<Activity> activities)
         throws IOException {
       try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
           new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), UTF_8))) {
         boolean first = true;
         for (Activity activity : activities) {
           if (!first) {
             // Print a newline after every activity.
             out.println();
           }
           writeActivity(out, activity);
           if (first) {
             first = false;
           }
         }
       }
     }

     private void writeActivity(PrintWriter out, Activity activity) {
       out.println(activity.day);
       out.println(activity.activityName);
       out.println(activity.supervisorName);
       out.println(activity.location);
       out.println(activity.paid);
     }

     /** Read activities from a file. */
     List<Activity> readActivities(File file) throws IOException {
       try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),
           UTF_8))) {
         List<Activity> result = new ArrayList<Activity>();
         while (true) {
           Activity activity = readActivity(in);
           result.add(activity);

           String line = in.readLine();
           if (line == null) {
             break; // Reached end of file.
           }
           if (!line.equals("")) {
             throw new IllegalStateException(
               "Expected empty line but got: <" + line + ">");
           }
         }
         return result;
       }
     }

     private Activity readActivity(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
       Activity activity = new Activity();
       activity.day = in.readLine();
       activity.activityName = in.readLine();
       activity.supervisorName = in.readLine();
       activity.location = in.readLine();
       activity.paid = in.readLine();
       return activity;
     }
   }
   ```

   The above code relies on the [try-with-resources feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) introduced in Java 7. For earlier version of Java, you need to rewrite both `try` blocks by reverting to the usual declare-try-finally-close style shown in the link.
3. From your UI event handling code like `actionPerformed()` methods, just call an instance of `ActivityManager` to read and write activities and convert between your UI components and the `Activity` class.